# How can I tell Cppcheck to skip a header file

Tags: googletest, cppcheck

Cppcheck scans all files in a project folder:

```
c:\projectfolder\main.c
c:\projectfolder\file.c
c:\projectfolder\file.h
c:\projectfolder\file_test.cc
```

`c:\projectfolder\file_test.cc` contains the following code

```
#include "c:/gtest/gtest.h"

extern "C"
{
    #include "TMyStruct.h"
}

TEST(Stack, Overflow)
{
    TMyStruct unterTest;
    EXPECT_EQ(1, TMyStruct_Init(&unterTest));
    EXPECT_GE(unterTest.variable, 9000);
}
```

File `file_test.cc` includes the gtest.h file

```
C:\gtest\gtest.h
```

All files in C:\gtest\ should not be tested.

I call

```
cppcheck.exe -ic:\gtest\ c:\projectfolder\ --enable=style --template="SomeError"
```

Errors are found and reported in `c:\projectfolder\file_test.cc` coming from the included `gtest.h` (detail: "too many #ifdef configurations").

How do I tell Cppcheck to not look at `C:\gtest\gtest.h` at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My project structure looks like this:

```
├── build
├── lib
│   └── dep
│       └── dep.h
├── src
│   ├── code.c
│   └── code.h
└── tests
    └── code_test.c
```

To suppress warnings for `lib` includes, I did this:

```
cppcheck --enable=all --suppress='*:lib/*' -Isrc -Itests ./src ./tests 1>/dev/null
```

Maybe this should work on Windows:

```
cppcheck.exe --suppress='*:c:\gtest\*' c:\projectfolder\
```

My Cppcheck version is 1.74.

Reference:

*[Allow ignoring results from header files](http://trac.cppcheck.net/ticket/2964)*

Answer (score 11):

I am a Cppcheck developer. I don't think you can skip a header file. Perhaps it should work like that.

Feel free to create a ticket about this: http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/cppcheck/

Comment: I would love to write /*ccpcheck::startignore*/ ... /*ccpcheck::endignore*/

Comment: I think that would be acceptable. I added a ticket (https://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/cppcheck/ticket/4377). I can't promise that we'll fix the ticket soon.. so if you have the time feel free to take a look at it.

Comment: well,... i am stuck otherwise :) How do i join the project?

Comment: Found a way around it for now. I call cppcheck for each files individually and leave out those that have external code imported via headers.

Comment: Any progress on this feature?

Comment: According to the manual (http://cppcheck.sourceforge.net/manual.pdf) page 7 states that the `i` option can be used to ignore files.

Comment: Nevermind, I was mistaken, `-i` is only for source files.