# Cppcheck: how to skip a directory of third party header files?

Tags: cppcheck

I call cppcheck on our own files in our source base. However, some source files include header files from third party libraries, say from `./lib/some_library/`. These are automatically parsed by cppcheck as well.

I don't want this, since I don't want to see warnings on third party code. Is there a way to get around this?

The difference with [how can i tell cppcheck to skip a header file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13591696/how-can-i-tell-cppcheck-to-skip-a-header-file) is that this post explicitly asks for skipping an entire directory, not just an individual header file.

Comment: `-i <dir>` Give path to ignore. Give several -i parameters to ignore several paths. Give directory name or filename with path as parameter. Directory name is matched to all parts of
 the path.

Comment: For me it says: `-i <dir or file>` Give a source file or source file directory to exclude from the check. **This applies only to source files so
                         header files included by source files are not matched.**
                         Directory name is matched to all parts of the path.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/38335737/792456

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how can i tell cppcheck to skip a header file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13591696/how-can-i-tell-cppcheck-to-skip-a-header-file)

Comment: Same issue here.  I am seeing issues from header files under directories which are explicitly excluded with `-i`.  This is not desirable.

Answer (score 13):

Another possibility would be to use suppressions via a file (see [manual](http://cppcheck.sourceforge.net/manual.pdf) chapter 7 "Listing suppressions in a file") or via [commandline](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38335737/7926064).

Your suppressions.txt could be

`*:/path/to/your/thirdpartylibs/*`

Which would exclude all errors from that path. The syntax is

`[error id]:[filename]:[line]`

with wildcard support for `*` (multiple characters) and `?` (single character).

The call to cppcheck would then be

```
cppcheck --suppressions-list=suppressions.txt .
```

Answer (score 10):

As per [cppcheck manual](http://cppcheck.sourceforge.net/manual.pdf):

**Excluding a file or folder from checking**
To exclude a file or folder, there are two options. The first option is to only provide the paths and files
you want to check.

```
cppcheck src/a src/b
```

All files under src/a and src/b are then checked.

The second option is to use -i, with it you specify files/paths to ignore. With this command no files in src/c are checked:

```
cppcheck -isrc/c src
```

This option does not currently work with the --project option and is only valid when supplying an input
directory.

To ignore multiple directories supply the -i multiple times. The following command ignores
both the src/b and src/c directories.

```
cppcheck -isrc/b -isrc/c
```

Answer (score 9):

I had a similar need to exclude reporting on a dedicated third party directory. To do so, I've used the `--suppress` option directly on the cli:

`"C:\Program Files\Cppcheck\cppcheck" --suppress=*:*3rdparty\* --language=c++ --enable=all --xml --xml-version=2 . 2> cppcheck-result.xml`

The interesting thing with `cppcheck` is that it will still show on the `stdout` that it's going through the 'suppressed' directory but in the result file, there won't be any files from the excluded directory in there. Looks like it could be further optimised.